# Excel Formula To Check If Values Are Present Otherwise Display Nothing - Also using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to use a formula that checks to see if there is a date in cells E9, F9, or G9, and if so, I want it to display the word "Open" without the parenthesis, in cell J9. Otherwise, if there is nothing in any of those 3 cells, I want J9 to display nothing at all.

The other half of the formula needs to check the same cells, and if there is a date in all 3, I want J9 to display "Done", without the parenthesis. So far, I have:

=IF(ISBLANK(E9:G9),"",IF(OR(ISBLANK(F9), ISBLANK(G9)),"Open","Done"))

This works, BUT, it also outputs the word "Done" in cells K9 and L9. I don't need these. How can I output ONLY to J9?

Here's a visual:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQIpy.png)

Answer (score 0):

There must be the same / similar formula in cells K9 and L9. Just delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need them to not show up and while it's easy to delete, I've made my workbook automated as much as possible as the user isn't well versed in excel. So having them delete 2 boxes all the time is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way!!

=IF(COUNT(E9:G9)=0,"",IF(OR(ISBLANK(E9), ISBLANK(F9), ISBLANK(G9)),"Open","Done"))

Can anyone else provide an easier way?